# How to display in Template data with non-latin characters coming from Django view

Tags: javascript, django, templates, unicode, view

I am retrieving through a Django view some data, which I want to display in a template. Most of the data are latin alphabet or numbers but I have some of them that they use non-latin characters or other symbols.

This cause a runtime error. Right now I include only "valid" values in my context dictionary:

```
if ((isinstance(value, (str, int, float)))):
                properties[key].append(value)

    context_dict["feature_properties"] = properties
```

But I am sure there is a more proper pythonic-Django way.
Printing my dictionary I get encoded values as:

```
'District_1': [u'\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd\ufffd
```

When I pass the data in the template I see in my console.log an error:

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string

Comment: Please show the full traceback

Comment: Thank you. But I don't actually get any errors during the execution of the view. I think the issue must appear later when I try to render the data in the template. data_from_django = {{ feature_properties | safe }};